# Numerical value of $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-s}\sqrt{y}\right)}{\sqrt{1-y} \cdot (sy-y+1)}\,ds\,dy $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Could somebody give me a numerical value for this integral?

$$I = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-s}\sqrt{y}\right)}{\sqrt{1-y} \cdot (sy-y+1)}\,ds\,dy $$

Comment: Here resolved by Seraphim mathematica.gr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=59475

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I\approx4.49076009892257799033708885767243640685411695804791115741588093621176851...$$

Comment: Thank you Vladimir! Maybe someone could give us a closed form, this is my next [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/937487/153012).