# Calculating in closed form $\int_0^1 \log(x)\left(\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2 \,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

What *real tools* excepting the ones provided here [Closed-form of $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937912/closed-form-of-int-01-frac-operatornameli-2-left-x-right-sqrt1-x2/1169757#1169757) would you like to recommend? I'm not against them, they might be great, but it seems they didn't lead anywhere for the version $\displaystyle \int_0^1  \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx$. Perhaps we can find an approach that covers both cases, also

$$\int_0^1 \log(x) \left(\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2 \,dx$$
that I would like to calculate.

Might we possibly expect a nice closed form as in the previous case? What do you propose?

**EDIT:** Thanks David, I had to modify it a bit to fix the convergence issue. Also, for the previous question there is already a **300 points** bounty offered for a full solution with all steps clearly explained.

Comment: We have $~I=J'(0),~$ where $~J(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1-x^k}{1-x^2}\cdot\text{Li}_2^2(x)~dx,~$ which is reminiscent of Euler's integral formula for generalized [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

Comment: $$\frac{21 \zeta (3)^2}{4}-\frac{67 \pi ^6}{8064}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2(n-k)^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)=\frac{2H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2}+\frac{4H_{n-1}}{n^3}$$
so:
$$ \text{Li}_2(x)^2 = \sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{2H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2}+\frac{4H_{n-1}}{n^3}\right) x^n\tag{1}$$
and since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n \log x}{1-x^2}\,dx = -\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+2m+1)^2}\tag{2}$$
we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\left(\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2\,dx = -\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{2H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2}+\frac{4H_{n-1}}{n^3}\right)\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+2m+1)^2}\tag{3}$$
and the problem boils down to the computation of a complicated Euler sum.

In order to perform partial summation, it is useful to recall that:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2}=\left(H_{N}^{(2)}\right)^2-H_{N}^{(4)},$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^3} = H_N^{(3)}H_{N-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_{n}^{(3)}}{n}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I think it's a good start. (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: about the bounty, are you so confident that a nice closed form for the $\phantom{}_4 F_3$ value shown by Claude Leibovici really exists, to waste $300$ reputation points? Sometimes, the most cunning approach does not work simply because it cannot work. Maybe that is one of these cases.

Comment: Yes, it definitely exists, and that form can be expressed in terms of trilogarithm. However, I would have liked to see a complete solution there.

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: why not just provide yours?

Comment: It's a known fact the connection with the trilogarithm, here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918680/closed-form-for-the-imaginary-part-of-textli-3-big-frac1i2-big/920995#920995, but I would have liked to see a complete approach of the problem.

Comment: All right, but I still do not get it. If it is just a matter of collecting pieces from there and there, why don't you do it by yourself?

Comment: From what I saw in that post it doesn't seem to be anything about collecting pieces from there and there at that stage, but I think one needs a clever strategy to get the answer. I'm just curious to see the full solution and I just offered 300 points bounty for that.

Comment: Actually I've construated [the integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/937912/153012) to get a deeper knowledge about the connection between that hypergeom series and that trilogarithm. On the other hand, if someone could find a closed-form of that hypergeom series, that would be the best. I've worked on this problem a lot. I've posted another related [integral problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/937487/153012).